# Prevent the dynamic allocation of string objects in gRPC messages

Tags: windows, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to prevent the dynamic allocation of string objects in gRPC messages. Currently we send large images in .NET gRPC implementation, which creates performance problems due to garbage collection. I saw that Arena prevents dynamic allocation of messages, except for string fields (ByteString in .NET I guess).

Is Arena already changed or going to changed for preventing the dynamic allocation of string fields. Or are there alternatives? We work on the Windows 10/x64 platform.

Comment: Even though there's been some requests to support features around garbage-free  (de)serialization (see github issues), this is currently not something that's supported. Supporting it would probably require large changes in the protobuf runtime, and possibly breaking changes to the public API (which is something we don't want). One day this might be available, but currently it's not something we are pursuing (it's a highly complicated design and the demand is not clear).

Comment: FTR one possibly related change that just went in is: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/7645 (not sure if it will be helpful in your case).